# Javascript - Change object with left-hand assignment in constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, extends

I've been experimenting with various ways to emulate classical inheritance in Javascript, and I've found some ways to do it.  However, I was curious why I couldn't do it one particular way, and how I could try to work around it.

I've tried this:

```
var squeaker = new squeek();

function monsterMaker(newMonster) {
    newMonster.type = "monster";
    newMonster.health = 10;
    return newMonster;
}

function squeek() {
    this.name = "squeek";
    this = monsterMaker(this);
}
```

I think I understand why this is happening, and I have figured out ways around it (namely jQuery's $.extend), but is there a way to change the newly created object in this way using a left-hand assignment, or a workaround, without using extra libraries?

Comment: You can't change the this reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to `this`, but you don't need to: your code, if it worked, would be equivalent to this code, which does work:

```
var squeaker = new squeek();

function monsterMaker(newMonster) {
    newMonster.type = "monster";
    newMonster.health = 10;
    return newMonster;
}

function squeek() {
    this.name = "squeek";
    monsterMaker(this); // sets properties on this
}
```

(Although JavaScript is pass-by-value, the "value" in this case is the entire `this` object, so in some respects it's like pass-by-reference.)

Comment: There is no need for the return in the `monsterMaker` function since the calling function already has a reference to the passed object and the return value isn't used.

Comment: @RobG: I dunno, I think it's pretty sensible for `monsterMaker` to support being called as `var monster = monsterMaker({})`. You say "the return value isn't used", but I don't think you can really know that; all you know is that `squeek` doesn't use it.

Comment: The call could pass an "anonymous" object, but that doesn't make much sense in the context of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't assign to [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). However, you don't need to! Just pass the instance (`this`) into `monsterMaker`, and that function adds some properties to it - just what you want. You don't need to return the object, or use the returned object - it's still `this`.

```
function Squeek() {
    this.name = "squeek";
    monsterMaker(this);
}

new Squeek(); // will have type and health
```

Comment: @user1689607: No - `Squeek` is a constructor function. `return this` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
var squeaker = new squeek();

function monsterMaker(newMonster) {
    this.type = "monster";
    this.health = 10;
}

function squeek() {
    this.name = "squeek";
    monsterMaker.call(this);
}
```

This way you can "decorate" any object you want with the monsterMaker function's properties.

But, thinking further, I think you have arrived to the point, where you would need prototypal-inheritance...

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it with prototypal inheritance, .  To see the console output, press F12 in Chrome or open FireBug in FireFox.  Chrome will give you an interactive object to drill down into.

```
function monsterMaker() {
    this.type = "monster";
    this.health = 10;
}

function squeek() {
    this.name = "squeek";
    //monsterMaker.call(this); // sets properties on this
}
squeek.prototype = new monsterMaker();
squeek.prototype.constructor = monsterMaker;

var squeaker = new squeek();

console.log(squeaker);
console.log(squeaker.name);
console.log(squeaker.type);
console.log(squeaker.health);
```

See it work here:

http://www.quirkscode.com/flat/forumPosts/extendThis/extendThis.html

Here are some links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited

Pulling from the second MDN link above, you can do it the "new JavaScript way" (ECMAScript 5) thus (includes library for extending and sample code - use console to see sample output:

```
// Original Author:  FireFly - Jonas Höglund - ##javascript channel
// on irc.freenode.net - see THANKS File

///////////////
// Library code
///////////////

var ExtendBase = {};

Object.defineProperty(ExtendBase, 'extend', {
    enumerable: false
    , value: function(obj) {
        'use strict';

        var descs = {}
        , objectInheritCounter = 0;

        objectInheritCounter += 1;

        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        descs[key] = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key)
        });

        return Object.create(this, descs);
    }
});

///////////////
// Sample Usage
///////////////

var Person = ExtendBase.extend({
  // missing: name

  // A person can tell you its name.
  talk: function() {
    return "Hello, I'm " + this.name
  }
})

var WorkingPerson = Person.extend({
  // missing: name, occupation

  // A working person also tells you their occupation when they talk.
  talk: function() {
    return Person.talk.call(this) + " and I am a " + this.occupation
  }
})

var p1 = WorkingPerson.extend({ name:"Harry", occupation:"wizard" })
console.log(p1.talk()); // "Hello, I'm Harry and I am a wizard"
```

See it work here:

http://www.quirkscode.com/flat/JSLearning/src/extend/extend.html

Comment: Bergi:  Could you please advise why you think this?  I am not exactly sure why - not being argumentative, just not sure why you said that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScipt is a prototype-based language. Rather than trying to ape classical object-orientated languages, give in to prototypes.

In this case, you want to create a `Monster` prototype; and a `Squeek` prototype based on the `Monster` prototype. Then you instantiate a `squeaker` from the `Squeek` object.

```
/* Set up your Monster prototype */
function Monster() { /* constructor */}
Monster.prototype.type = "monster";
Monster.prototype.health = 10;

/* Now use the prototype of a Monster to create the prototype of a Squeek */
function Squeek() { /* constructor */ }
Squeek.prototype = new Monster(); // thanks Bergi and RobG
Squeek.prototype.constructor = Squeek; // thanks RobG
Squeek.prototype.name = "squeek";

/* Now let's instantiate a Squeek */
var squeaker = new Squeek();
console.log(squeaker.name); // squeek
console.log(squeaker.type); // monster
console.log(squeaker.health); // 10
console.log(squeaker.constructor === Squeek); // true

var monster = new Monster();
console.log(monster.name); // undefined
```

Comment: Why do you set `Monster.prototype.name` to `"squeek"`?

Comment: Much better to assign an *instance* of `Monster` to `Squeek`'s prototype. Also, you want to modify the constructor property of `Squeek.prototype`, since that's the property that instances of `Squeek` will inherit. The Squeek constructor is an instance of the bulit–in `Function` object, so that's what its constructor property (which it inherits from its `[[Prototype]]`) should reference.